# How to unset an event listener in OpenLayers 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

I am trying to use '.un' to unset the 'single-click' event listener. I have tried all the ways available. How can I do this?

```
measurePoint() {
  const that = this;
  this.mapObj.on('singleclick', (e) => {
    if (this.measureType === 'point') {
      const coods = e.coordinate;
      // some code here
    }
  });
}

measure(type: any) {
  this.mapObj.un('singleclick');
  // some code here
  if (type === 'point') {
    this.measurePoint();
  }
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.mapObj.removeLayer(this.vector);
  this.mapObj.un('singleclick');
  // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `un` you must use a named function for `on`

Without a named function you must save the event key

```
eventKey = this.mapObj.on('singleclick', ...
```

and use

```
unByKey(eventKey);
```

imported as

```
import {unByKey) from 'ol/Observable';
```